# Ubuntu Apache https time out status. Though http works fine

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt

Created ssl certificate using let's encrypt for apache. It is showing request timed out every time.

```
 nc -zvw 1 studytact.ml 443
 nc: connect to studytact.ml port 443 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

here is my ssl config

000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName studytact.ml

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/video-poc/public
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/video-poc

    PassengerAppType node
    PassengerStartupFile bin/www.js

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/video-poc/public>
        Allow from all
        #Options -MultiViews
    # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl-error.log

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/studytact.ml/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/studytact.ml/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

I am confused as to what is wrong here

Comment: can you double check if you listening on 443 on your server side?

Still not sure what distribution you use. For Debian and RedHat based OSs the command looks like this:
```ss -tulpan | grep 443```

Also make sure that you get requests from your client. 
On your server start tcpdump:
```tcpdump tcp port 443```
Keep it running while running your nc command on your client.

Comment: For first command it's giving me `tcp   LISTEN  0   128   *:443        *:* `. In tcpdump : `ip-172-31-29-117.ap-south-1.compute.internal.43476 > ec2-13-234-96-121.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com.https: Flags [S], cksum 0x3826 (incorrect -> 0x4415), seq 2982541159, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 588631504 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Yes it was a security group issue with aws. If you have firewall enabled , then check that too